# Consistency proof of the M-estimator when our parameter space is no longer compact?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, estimation, parameter-estimation

Suppose that we have a parameter space $\Theta$ that is NOT compact.

The M-estimator is defined to be $\widehat{\theta}_{n}$ which maximizes $M_{n}\left(\theta\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{\theta}\left(X_{i}\right)$
and $\theta^{*}$ maximizes $M\left(\theta\right)=\mathbb{E}\left[m_{\theta}\left(X\right)\right]$,
for some functions $m_{\theta}$ and $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}$ random
variables i.i.d. from a pdf $f$.

The expectation $\mathbb{E}$
is with respect to $f$. Assume that there exists a compact
set $S\in \Theta$ such that $\theta^{*}\in X$ and

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{\theta\in\mathcal{\Theta}\cap S^{c}}m_{\theta}\left(X\right)\right]<M\left(\theta^{*}\right).\label{eq:lessinexpect}
\end{equation}
How can we show that almost surely, $\widehat{\theta}_{n}$ is in the compact set $S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am maybe 6 years late. But since I have encountered the same problem recently, would post my solution for future reference.

Let $A_n = \{\omega\in \Omega, \hat{\theta}_n(\omega)\in \mathcal{H}\cap K^c\}$. Define
\begin{align*}
    A = \limsup A_n
\end{align*}
By the assumption, $Y_i$ are $i.i.d.$. If we permute finitely many index of $Y_i$, the value of $\hat{\theta_n}$ is unchanged for sufficiently large $n$. i.e. The occurrence of $A$ is unchanged by finite permutation of index of $Y_i$. By Hewitt-Savage Zero One Law
\begin{align*}
    P(A) \in \{0,1\}
\end{align*}
To prove $P(A)=0$, it is sufficient to prove $P(A)\neq 1$.

For the sake of contradiction, suppose $P(A)=1$. We note that when $\hat{\theta_n}\in \mathcal{H}\cap K^c$, we have
\begin{align*}
    \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n m(\hat{\theta_n})\leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \sup_{\theta\in \mathcal{H}\cap K^c}m(\theta)
\end{align*}
This event occurs infinitely often on $A$, so we have the following
\begin{align*}
    \liminf\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n m(\hat{\theta_n})1_{A}\right)\leq\limsup\left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \sup_{\theta\in \mathcal{H}\cap K^c}m(\theta)1_{A}\right)
\end{align*}
By law of large number, $P(A)=1$ and $\mathbb{E}( |\sup_{\theta\in \mathcal{H}\cap K^c}m(\theta)|)<\infty$, we have
\begin{align*}
    \limsup\left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \sup_{\theta\in \mathcal{H}\cap K^c}m(\theta)1_{A}\right) = \mathbb{E}\sup_{\theta\in \mathcal{H}\cap K^c}m(\theta)
\end{align*}

On the other hand
\begin{align*}
    \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n m(\theta^*)1_{A}\leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n m(\hat{\theta_n})1_{A}
\end{align*}
By law of large number and $P(A)=1$, the LHS converges to $\mathbb{E}m(\theta^*)$.
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}(m(\theta^*))\leq \liminf \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n m(\hat{\theta_n})1_{A}\right)\leq \mathbb{E}\sup_{\theta\in \mathcal{H}\cap K^c}m(\theta)
\end{align*}
This contradicts
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}\sup_{\theta\in \mathcal{H}\cap K^c}m(\theta)< \mathbb{E}(m(\theta^*))
\end{align*}
We conclude $P(A)=0$.

Next, apply the inequality of $\limsup$ of sets
\begin{align*}
    \limsup P(A_n) \leq P(\limsup A_n) = P(A) = 0
\end{align*}
This concludes $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(A_n)=0$.

Comment: Thanks very much, greatly appreciate your answer, even if its 6 years later!

Comment: @Zorualyh Can you please help me to answer this question 6 months later? 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4760420/maximizing-the-likelihood-over-the-truncated-support-always-leads-to-strictly-gr